# Check if discord bot command's arguments match with the format specified by the commands config

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make something that checks if the arguments provided for a command match with what the command expected the arguments to be.

For example;
The `config` command expects the first argument to be `show`, `set`, or `reset`
And if `set` or `reset` are used, it requires 2 more arguments:

```js
module.exports = class Config {
 constructor() {
  this.cmdconf = {
   // arguments key
   args: '< show [setting] | set <option> <value> | reset <option> <value> >',
  };
 }
 run() {
  // command
 }
};
```

Key: `<required>`, `[optional]`
`<option>` being the setting to change and `<value>` being the value to change it to
When I run the command I want to check if all the arguments were provided

Is there a way I can do this easily and have it work for every command without writing a checker for each command individually?

Edit: I gave a more advanced example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you structure your commands like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'config',
  execute (message, args) => {
```

You could add an `args` property as an `array`:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'config',
  args: 'show [setting] | set <option> <value> | reset <option> <value>'
  execute (message, args) => {
```

---

In your command handler, add these lines:

```js
const isReq = (string) => {
 const matched = string.match(/^<(.+)>$/);
 return matched ? matched[1] : false;
};

if (command.args) {
 var everythingAccountedFor = false;
 const options = command.args.split(' | ');
 for (const option of options) {
  const [definer, ...values] = option.split(' ');
  if (definer !== args[0]) continue;

  if (
   values.some((word, index) => isReq(word) && args[index + 1] !== isReq(word))
  )
   break;

  everythingAccountedFor = true;
  break;
 }
 if (!everythingAccountedFor)
  return message.channel.send(
   `You're message did not provide a required argument.\nHere is the command structure: \`${command.args}\``
  );
}
```

---

Here's an example I set up in a testing Discord server:

[image: example]

Comment: This is useful however when it comes to more than one argument for the command I'm still not sure how to do that. I edited my question with a more advanced and detailed explanation of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the more in-depth question. I'll try to edit my answer right now.

Comment: Disregard my incorrect form of "you're", I'm very sleepy :p

Comment: Thank you I will be sure to take a look and see how well this works.